# Send is not a function discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to send a message to channel but I keep getting Error: send is not a function.I have been stuck on this problem for over an hour.

What I have tried:
using sendMessage
tried reading the discord.js documentation but it doesnt seem to be working at all.

Here is my code:

```
//Grab the Discord Library
const Discord = require("discord.js");

//What will connect to the server.
const bot = new Discord.Client();

//
bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.log("Connected as " + bot.user.tag)

  //Shows and set the activity of the user.
  bot.user.setActivity("El Professor build me", {type: "Watching"})
  //Inform you of the servers this bot is connected to.
  bot.guilds.forEach((guild) => {
    console.log(guild.name)
    guild.channels.forEach((channel) => {
      console.log(` - ${channel.name} ${channel.type} ${channel.id}`)
    })
    //Voice Channel ID = 
  })
  var generalChannel = bot.channels.get("123456789").send("Hello World")
})
```

Error message:

```
C:\Users\F4_ALFA\documents\FirstDiscordBot\index.js:21
  var generalChannel = bot.channels.get("123456789").send("Hello World")
                                                              ^

TypeError: bot.channels.get(...).send is not a function
    at Client.bot.on (C:\Users\F4_ALFA\documents\FirstDiscordBot\index.js:21:63)
    at Client.emit (events.js:194:15)
    at WebSocketConnection.triggerReady (C:\Users\F4_ALFA\documents\FirstDiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConn
ection.js:125:17)
    at WebSocketConnection.checkIfReady (C:\Users\F4_ALFA\documents\FirstDiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConn
ection.js:141:61)
    at GuildCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\F4_ALFA\documents\FirstDiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\Gui
ldCreate.js:13:31)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\F4_ALFA\documents\FirstDiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocke
tPacketManager.js:103:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\F4_ALFA\documents\FirstDiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnecti
on.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\F4_ALFA\documents\FirstDiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnect
ion.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\F4_ALFA\documents\FirstDiscordBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
```

Comment: Are you sure that ID points to a TextChannel? You can check by posting `<#ID>` in the server of the channel and see if its resolving to a mention

Answer (score 1):

Discord.js uses cache and your code has no '.cache', you should try

`bot.channels.cache.get('id').send('Hello world!')`

Answer (score 0):

The [`channels`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=channels) property returns a [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection) with pair of `ID` and `Channel object`.

> The [`Channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel) class could represent any channel in discord. You couldn't send any messages through it because it doesn't have `send()` method.

Comment: but if you do a get you should get a Channel object

Answer (score 0):

I’ve used this before `client.guilds.find(x => x.name === "ChatLogs").channels.find(y => y.name === "server-testing1").send(botEmbed)` try that